# DownloadManager could not download or open content from google drive URI?

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I am trying to download content from Google Drive URI but failed to open the content, but the content is being downloaded in download folder with whatever size of file. While content named URL 2 is being downloaded sucessfully and also open in supported app. Please point out where I am lacking. Do I need some special afford or this code can be managed to do so.

How can I download from Google Drive?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

// URL 1
 String Download_path = "https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bBd6Q4YyOMdYDV_v3boyYlrcecoaDXwOZw";
 // URL 2
 //String Download_path = "http://www.vogella.de/img/lars/LarsVogelArticle7.png";

 String Download_ID = "DOWNLOAD_ID";

 SharedPreferences preferenceManager;
 DownloadManager downloadManager;

   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);

       preferenceManager = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
       downloadManager = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

       Button btnDownload = (Button)findViewById(R.id.download);
       btnDownload.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Uri Download_Uri = Uri.parse(Download_path);
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Download_Uri);
      request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI
              | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
               .setAllowedOverRoaming(false)
               .setTitle("Demo")
               .setDescription("Something useful. No, really.")
               .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "test.JPG")
              .setMimeType("application/.jpg")
                .allowScanningByMediaScanner();

       //.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/mnt/sdcard/Myfolder", "file_name.extension");

    long download_id = downloadManager.enqueue(request);

    //Save the download id
    Editor PrefEdit = preferenceManager.edit();
    PrefEdit.putLong(Download_ID, download_id);
    PrefEdit.commit();
   }});
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try it:

```
String cookie = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(Download_path); 
request.addRequestHeader("Cookie", cookie);

long download_id = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
```

I guess you need authentication info (session id, etc...) of your google account, which is managed by cookie.

Download manager does not insert your WebView's cookie to its request, so you need to pass the cookie value to the request's header manually.

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your public drive link by following: [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65322279/8362967)

then use the converted link